# Android Studio: program to display current users data with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing an app that after logging in, you can view data of the Realtime Database (name and email), but only your own data (from the user who has logged in). For example, if you log in with user "hi@gmail.com" you only see your e-mail and your name. The activity of Log in is already done and it Works with FireBase Authentication. But when I log in there is no data displayed. Where is my mistake?

I attach you my code of Android Studio:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;



public class Documentation extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseUser user;
String uid_number;





FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,MyRecyclerViewHolder> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("users");
    user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert user != null;
    uid_number=user.getUid();
    displayComment();

}

private void displayComment() {
    options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(databaseReference,Post.class)
            .build();


    adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, MyRecyclerViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Post model) {

                    holder.txt_name.setText(model.getName());
                    holder.txt_email.setText(model.getEmail());




                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public MyRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item,viewGroup,false);
                    return new MyRecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
                }
            };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

In my Firebase rules I have:

```
   {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I attach you an image of my database:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is some mistake because when I log in no data is displayed. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the email & name from the Firebase Database, firstly set your database reference and variables as well.

```
String email, name;
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
```

then make a method that uses ValueEventListener

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
          name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
 }
    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

}

then you setText it to whatever you're getting at.

If its from Firebase Authentication, you can get your email by this line and setText it

```
String email = user.getEmail();
```

Comment: its a bit late but pls kindly mark it as the correct answer... Would greatly appreciate it